# How can I check multiple collider Triggers at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an aircraft in my game that is controlled by the player. I want it to get destroyed after it collides with something. The aircraft has many colliders on it, so im using an array. Heres my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AircraftDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
public Collider[] Colliders;
public GameObject Aircraft;


 private void OnTriggerEnter(Colliders collision)
 {
    DestroyAircraft();
 }






 public void DestroyAircraft()
 {
    Destroy(Aircraft);
 }

}
```

Im getting the obvious error here, type or namespace 'Colliders' could not be found. How can I check if any collider within my array gets triggered?

Comment: Keep in mind, although using `DestroyAircraft();` looks dumb, because all it does is `Destroy(Aircraft);` , there will be particles and stuff happening before it gets destroyed. this will be added in `DestroyAircraft()` before the `Destroy(Aircraft); ` is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a better approach is to use `OnCollisionEnter` instead of `OnTriggerEnter`

Comment: so if I say `private void OnCollisionEnter(Colliders collider)` ? Would that work? Or is my format here wrong

Comment: if your aircraft has any collider, and while playing , it collides with a building for example , you have to detect the collision that just happened , so you add a `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`  then call the destroy methode

Comment: Thanks for the response, The colliders are not attacked to the aircraft, but rather are children of it. This allows me to have a different collider for each wing, body piece ETC. I need to check if any of them collide with a building (for example) and destroy the craft. This is why I originally used an array rather than just checking the aircrafts collider

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the basics of Collision here. You don't need to reference the Colliders using an array.

Both OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter are called when the gameobject to which the script is attached collides with another collider. They return the collider with which it has collided.

So in your case its better to have a single collider on the parent gameobject rather than separate Colliders.

If you really want to have separate colliders for the airplane's body part then you need to add a collision checking script to each of the gameobject or you can add the collision checking script to your obstacles like building and have all your Airplane parts in a single tag.

[Check out this guide on Unity collision](https://vionixstudio.com/2019/09/04/unity-collider-explained/)

Comment: Yes thank you, I realised that I was doing it in a dumb way. Ive added a new collider for the whole Aircraft and it works. But now I have a different issue. 
The game is crashing when I try to spawn in the new Mesh for the explosion. Im making a post on it, Ill send link here if you could please help me

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952166/my-pc-freezes-and-crashes-when-calling-this-void) Heres the post