# My PC freezes and crashes when calling this Void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Like the title says, my PC freezes and crashes when this void is called. I assume it's spawning huge amounts of `BrokenAircraft` but I cannot figure out a fix. Here's the snippet:

```
public void DestroyAircraft()
{
    Vector3 AircraftPos = Aircraft.transform.position;
    Destroy(Aircraft);
    GameObject.Instantiate(BrokenAircraft, AircraftPos, Quaternion.identity);
    foreach(Transform t in BrokenAircraft.transform)
    {
        Rigidbody rb = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody;
        //MeshCollider mc = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshCollider)) as MeshCollider;
        
        if(rb != null)
        {
            rb.AddExplosionForce(Random.Range(minExplode, maxExplode), transform.position, radius);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many transforms does this process? Have you tried debugging or lowering the number of transforms.

Comment: *"I assume..."*. Why? Why would you assume when you can test?

Comment: Originally I tested just the `BrokenAircraft` in start, there are about 20 transforms, and it worked. On start, everything worked fine. I then just wanted it to only happen when you crashed. So I changed it to be what I sent now, its ment to do exactly what on Start did earlier, but instead it crashes the PC. Im making sure there are no scripts attached to anything in the `BrokenAircraft` prefab to be safe

Comment: because running the game causes the pc to freeze as soon as the script is Invoked, and then PC restarts. Its happened 4 times, I cant really test anything because of this

Answer (score 0):

So after testing a few times without the for loop, it still caused the issue. But I was able to Stop play before it froze entirly. There was an error saying I cannot destroy the GameObject because it was refrenced as `public Transform` instead of `public GameObject` swapping this fixed it. Thanks for the assistance from everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why / how that would crash the PC - I'd suggest diagnosing issues outside Unity with the PC (HD space, drivers, virus scans etc). However, `Destroy` and `Instantiate` are expensive processes, as is `GetComponent`. Better to enable / disable instead and use an object pool to cache resources: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling

```
public void DestroyAircraft()
{
    Vector3 AircraftPos = Aircraft.transform.position;
    Aircraft.SetActive(false);
    //GameObject.Instantiate(BrokenAircraft, AircraftPos, Quaternion.identity);
//Retrieve from object pool here instead
    foreach(Transform t in BrokenAircraft.transform)
    {
        //Rigidbody rb = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody;
        //MeshCollider mc = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshCollider)) as MeshCollider;
// when object pooling these vars are already cached
        
        if(rb != null)
        {
            rb.AddExplosionForce(Random.Range(minExplode, maxExplode), transform.position, radius);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I discovered the issue. There were 2. First is: using the foreach loop was doing too much and causing slow downs. Second is I had used a Mesh Collider on each fragment of the BrokenAircraft, which was stupid. I'm not home right now, but I assume these are the issues based off of replies here and on Reddit. I will test when I get back

Comment: So after testing a few times without the for loop, it still caused the issue. But I was able to Stop play before it froze entirly. There was an error saying I cannot destroy the GameObject because it was refrenced as `public Transform` instead of `public GameObject` swapping this fixed it. Thanks for the assistance from everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this was the intended code, just make sure not to call this repeatedly - I guess once Aircraft is destroyed we better set it to "null"?:

```
public void DestroyAircraft()
{
    Vector3 AircraftPos = Aircraft.transform.position;
    Destroy(Aircraft);
    Aircraft = null;

    // Important: Get a GameObject reference of that new destroyed aircraft
    var destroyedAircraft = GameObject.Instantiate(BrokenAircraft, AircraftPos, Quaternion.identity);
    // Iterate over the destroyed aircraft, not its original prefab "BrokenAircraft"
    foreach(Transform t in destroyedAircraft.transform)
    {
        Rigidbody rb = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody;
        
        if(rb != null)
        {
            rb.AddExplosionForce(Random.Range(minExplode, maxExplode), transform.position, radius);
        }
    }
}
```